# Creating Form Elements for the Ipad in Storyboard

Tags: forms, ipad, storyboard

This is the first time I've ever used storyboard and designed an app and it seems your everyday form items aren't available... Is this true?

I've found text views and labels but I really need to use radio buttons, check boxes, and drop down lists.

Do these not exist in storyboard? Do I have to do some round about way to make them?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to Interface Builder? I don't believe there are default radio buttons, check boxes or drop down lists, which is why you wouldn't have been able to find them. There are things like UISwitch which can be used for on/off though you'll probably have to write any other custom functionality yourself.

Comment: So I'm confused. I'm a web programmer. I've seen apps with these features, how did they go about creating them?

I'm used to the classic <asp:Dropdownlist> and <asp:Checkbox> or the html method.

Comment: Storyboard is used to manage how views interact with each other. I'd recommend you find a tutorial on the basics, I recommend Stanfords iTunes U lessons. The latest one is on iOS 5 I believe.